# " replaced by ""

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

redshift unload command is replacing " by "".
example :

```
UNLOAD($$ select '"Jane"' as name $$)
TO 's3://s3-bucket/test_' 
iam_role arn:aws:iam::xxxxxx:role/xxxxxx' 
HEADER 
CSV 
DELIMITER ',' 
ALLOWOVERWRITE
```

The output looks like : `""Jane""`

If I run the same command with `select 'Jane' as name` , the output shows without quote at all like `Jane`. But I need the output to be `"Jane"`

Comment: [ADDQUOTES](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html)? Did you check the command options?

Comment: when using ADDQUOTES I have this error:  ```Invalid operation: ADDQUOTES is not supported for UNLOAD to CSV```

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for the unloaded file to be in CSV format and CSV format says that if you want a double quote in your data you need to escape it with another double quote.  See https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180

So Redshift is doing exactly as you requested.  Now if you just want a comma delimited file then you don't want to use "CSV" as this will add all the necessary characters to make the file fully compliant with the CSV specification.

This choice will come down to what tool or tools are reading the file and if they expect an rfc compliant CSV or just a simple file where fields are separated by commas.

This is a gripe of mine - tools that say they read CSV but don't follow the spec.  If you say CSV then follow the format. Or call what you read something different, like CDV - comma delimited values.